# Spelling test check not functioning (python)

Tags: python

Very simple error that I've had for quite a while now that I seem to be missing, and it's really bugging me

```
studentspelling = input ('Spelling: ')
spellingnumber = y6wordlist.index(studentspelling)
if studentspelling == y6wordlist[spellingnumber]:
    print ('Correct. Awarded 2 points.')
    total = total + 2
else:
    print ('Incorrect answer. Awarded no points.')
    total = total
```

However when I try to input a word during the spelling test that is NOT the word assigned to `y6wordlist[spellingnumber]` I get this error:

```
ValueError: 'dgfh' is not in list
```

now obviously I know that it's not in the list, but none of my code has said that it has to be, or at least I don't think so. I have tried a number of things such as using 'elif' but to no degree of success. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the complete traceback, not just the error; it will tell you (or at least us) where the problem is happening, instead of making us guess.

Comment: Instead of searching the whole list I think you should check against one element of the list. The student could simply enter the correct spelling of another word.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't make much sense. `index` is asking for the index where the student spelling is found. Then you're checking whether the value at that index is the student spelling. How could that be anything but true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` method will raise a ValueError if the value is not in the list:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a.index(1)
0
>>> a.index(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 4 is not in list
>>>
```

You can test whether the word is in the list using `in`:

```
if word in mylist:
    i = mylist.index(word)
    # do something
else:
    # do something different
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
spellingnumber = y6wordlist.index(studentspelling)
```

will result in a `ValueError` if the word is not in the list

** incidentally, if you raise the error, you automatically know the word isn't right**

You could use:

```
try:
    spellingnumber = y6wordlist.index(studentspelling)
    # and you could just go straight to this
    print ('Correct. Awarded 2 points.')
    total = total + 2

except ValueError: 
    print ('Incorrect answer. Awarded no points.')
```

or something similar

Answer (score 0):

`index()` raises a `ValueError` when the argument (`studentspelling`) is not in the list.

If you have (or create) a variable that keeps track of the current question then I think you meant to write:

```
current_question = 0
student_spelling = input ('Spelling: ')
if student_spelling == y6wordlist[current_question]:
    print ('Correct. Awarded 2 points.')
    total = total + 2
else:
    print ('Incorrect answer. Awarded no points.')
    total = total

current_question = current_question + 1
```

This does: give the spelling of the current question/word. Then, lookup the correctly spelling word up at position `current_question` in `y6wordlist` and see if it's the same as `student_spelling`. If so then the student has spelled the word correctly and otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for the list data structure shows:

> list.index(x): Return the index in the list of the first item whose
>   value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

Since you're preferring to test for membership, rather than get the index number of a value that may not be present, you might instead do:

```
if studentspelling in y6wordlist
```

Alternatively, you could also have a try/catch block:

```
try:
    spellingnumber = y6wordlist.index(studentspelling)
    print ('Correct. Awarded 2 points.')
    total = total + 2
except ValueError:
    print ('Incorrect answer. Awarded no points.')
    total = total
```